# Can I upgrade the processor in my Toshiba Satellite L455?

Tags: cpu, upgrade, toshiba-laptop

I have a **Toshiba Satellite L455-S5975** which is about three years old. The processor is currently an `Intel Celeron 900`. Does anyone know if it is possible to upgrade this to a newer one?

I have heard the `Core 2 Duo T6600` is a compatible replacement for my processor on other brands of computers, and I know the two have the same socket type (`PGA478`). I mostly need to know if this or any other newer processors are compatible with the Satellite's motherboard.

Comment: not a hard and fast rule but the other options for the same model would be a safe bet.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can do it.

[They](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f108/cpu-upgrade-461463.html) did it with an Intel T7250, which looks pretty cheap on ebay (under $20).  Definitely monitor your temps afterward and apply new thermal paste.

Here is another post where the guys give other CPU options: [here](http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/Satellite-Laptops-all-other/Another-processor-upgrade-question-L455-S5975/td-p/255737).  Just double check your chipset.  Looks like you should be okay and if you're successful, that'll be a huge boost for you!

Unfortunately no "how-to's" nor "this will definitely works", but it sure looks like it.

Good luck!